# Как правильно организовать структуру Laravel-проекта?

Tags: laravel, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу просто разобраться с тем, как правильно строить приложения на данном фреймворке. В asp.net mvc у меня с этим проблем не возникло, разрабатывал вполне приличные приложения. Я знаю про существование репозиториев, сервис провайдеров, контрактов в Laravel, но может кто-нибудь объяснит мне порядок их взаимодействия? Можно просто указать ссылку на github, или нарисовать примерную схему. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в данном вопросе.

Использую Laravel 5.4

Comment: Laravel это MVC архитиктура

Comment: @Dmitriy, я прекрасно это понимаю. Я могу написать просто приложение, которое, к примеру, будет в контроллере получать данные из модели, и выводить их во вьюшку. Ну или добавлять в базу данных, тут уж сами додумайте как вам нравится. Смысл в том, что взаимодействие будет таким: View -> Controller -> Model. Если условно. Но как сюда добавить контракты, сервис-контейнеры и связывание в них интерфейса и реализации, мне немного не понятно. Читать документацию можно  и два часа, но на наглядном примере мне хватит 10 минут чтобы разобраться. Лучшее понимание, в моем случае, приходит через практику.